# XElement Path Validation

Tags: linq, xelement

I am trying to validate Elements and Attributes exist in an XElement.  Basically, I was wondering if anyone had a generic way to check if a give path is null.  I don't have access to System.Xml.XPath (doing this for compact framework).

Basically what I have is:

```
<root value"1000">
  <element1>test<element1>
  <element2>1<element2>
  ....
  <element30>
    <subElement1>stuff</subElement1>
  </element30>
</root>
```

Now I know you can "if this is null do this and that".  But since there is upwards of 30 elements that can be under root, which are optional elements, I need a way to grab the value if it exists and convert it to the correct type (which I know) in a nice compact way.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is validate that the XML document adheres to given rules or format you might want to use XML Schema for that rather than LINQ.

Comment: They don't exist in the SDK.  No Schemas, no xpath... Really not much of anything.